# How do I join between two tables and count by child column value

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to get list of courses based on highest enrolled users using join between `courses` and `enrolled_courses`.

Initially I tried like:

```
const enrolled = await Enroled_courses.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'courseId',
        [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('courseId')), 'count'],
    ],
    group: ['Enroled_courses.courseId'],
    order: [[Sequelize.col("count"), "DESC"]],
    limit: req.query.limit || 10,
})
```

Which is giving me result:

```
0: {courseId: '9839b20b-d45c-4c93-ba52-81d53839feb2', count: '7'}
1: {courseId: '56418231-8bf1-40c0-9ad1-b67dae108151', count: '7'}
2: {courseId: 'bac70dd1-3cf9-4a6e-a95d-5e716df6a8bd', count: '6'}
3: {courseId: 'e6f73cbe-3a6c-44fd-9c35-e03a8e97cf49', count: '3'}
4: {courseId: '49dde467-e990-4ac6-9087-ada4e078163f', count: '2'}
5: {courseId: '6783ba4f-3c4b-43c8-b2d7-8940d5bb653a', count: '2'}
```

But the above is just the courseId and number of time it is enrolled but I need to get the course data as well like `title` , `desc` etc from `Course` table

I tried to join between `Course` and `EnroledCourse` like this:

```
const enrolled = await Course.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Enroled_courses, 
        as: 'enroled_courses',
        attributes: [
            'courseId',
            [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('courseId')), 'count'],
        ]
    }],
    group: ['Enroled_courses.courseId'],
    limit: req.query.limit || 10
})
```

But I keep getting error:

`original: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "Enroled_courses"`

Comment: Try to add `duplicating: false` into your include. Seems like your question is related to [sequelize issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4446#issuecomment-138288921)

Comment: @Jaood_xD I have already tried that and it is giving `error: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "Enroled_courses"` error

Comment: This could be fixed by `subQuery: false`.  otherwise, please post the generated query.

Comment: Have you established relation between these two models with `belongsTo`/`hasMany`?